# Multiple if statement while updating data

Tags: java

It is about updating data via a web request, and the data is to be updated only if the parameter data is not empty. I have checked about the common refactoring methods but seem can't think of any better way to do.

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getFieldA()) {
  dataModel.setFieldA(request.getFieldA());
  jpaRepository.save(dataModel);
  auditChange(request.getFieldA());
}
```

The problem arises when a new field is added. If using the similar construct to add a new if statement, it will update the database twice, which seem not desirable.

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getFieldB()) {
  dataModel.setFieldB(request.getFieldB());
  jpaRepository.save(dataModel);
  auditChange(request.getFieldB());
}
```

If adding on the original "if statement" checking, it avoids multiple database update, but it's also not a very good way in term of clean code and being open for extension if a third field comes in.

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getFieldA()) || StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getFieldB()) {
                dataModel.setFieldA(StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getFieldA()) ? request.getFieldA() : dataModel.getFieldA());
                dataModel.setFieldB(StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getFieldB()) ? request.getFieldB() : dataModel.getFieldB());
                jpaRepository.save(dataModel);
                
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getFieldA())) {
                    auditChange(request.getFieldA());
                }

                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getFieldB())) {
                    auditChange(request.getFieldB());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just move `jpaRepository.save()` out of the `if` statements and put it below them, so:

```
boolean updated = false;
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getFieldB()) {
  dataModel.setFieldB(request.getFieldB());
  updated = true;
  auditChange(request.getFieldB());
}
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getFieldA()) {
  dataModel.setFieldA(request.getFieldA());
  updated = true;
  auditChange(request.getFieldA());
}
if (updated)
  jpaRepository.save(dataModel);
```

or if `auditChange` has to be done after the update to the database:

```
boolean updated = false;
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getFieldB()) {
  dataModel.setFieldB(request.getFieldB());
  updated = true;
}
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getFieldA()) {
  dataModel.setFieldA(request.getFieldA());
  updated = true;
}
if (updated)
  jpaRepository.save(dataModel);
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getFieldB()) {
  auditChange(request.getFieldB());
}
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getFieldA()) {
  auditChange(request.getFieldA());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use case similarity to PATCH request - only define changed field in the request. (Note that in your implementation, how do you set a field to be null on purpose?)

Take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-json-patch for details json patch implementation in Spring Boot

Answer (score 0):

Let JPA/Hibernarte handle updated/changed fields of entity in transaction.
Simply add annotations `@DynamicInsert` `@DynamicUpdate` along with `@Entity` on your Hibernate entity pojo.

something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public class User {
//...
}
```

`@DynamicInsert` annotation says that, For inserting, should this entity use dynamic sql generation where only non-null columns get referenced in the prepared sql statement?

`@DynamicUpdate` annotation says that, For updating, should this entity use dynamic sql generation where only changed columns get referenced in the prepared sql statement?

**Note:** If you find your sql `insert` operations are not working fine, you can remove `@DynamicInsert`. (Sometimes it does for me so.)

Answer (score 0):

The obligatory lambda and streams solution:

```
     static boolean updateField(String newValue, Consumer<String> setter ) {
             if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(newValue)) {
                 setter.accept(newValue);
                 auditChange(newValue);
                 return true;
             }
             return false;
     }
...

         if (Stream.of(
                 updateField(request.getFieldA(), v -> model.setFieldA(v)),
                 updateField(request.getFieldB(), v -> model.setFieldB(v))
                 ).anyMatch(b -> b))
         {
             jpaRepository.save(dataModel);
         }
```

`anyMatch` stops when it find the first true value, but that's OK because we did our side-effects up front when we created the stream.